# Copy & Paste from one Sheet to another Sheet if dates match condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, date, copy-paste

I am trying to create a VBA that obtains the current day, and copies the value from C18 in the DATA sheet, and pastes it two columns to the right of the matching date that is found in the DAILY CLOSE sheet.

I've tried coding it this way and it keeps resorting to "No date found."

I don't know where I'm going wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim dClose As Worksheet
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim fRow As Integer
    Dim fDate As String
    Dim qtr As Range
    
    
    Set data = Sheets("data")
    Set dClose = Sheets("daily close")
    Set qtr = dClose.Range("A:A, P:P, AE:AE, AT:AT")
    fDate = Date
    
    
    With dClose
        Set fCell = qtr.Find(fDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
            fRow = fCell.Row
            data.Range("C18").Copy
            dClose.Cells(fRow, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        Else
            MsgBox ("No date found")
        
        End If
    End With


  
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim fDate As Date`

Comment: Not related to your question, but as you're using `xlPasteValues`, you might as well do `dClose.Cells(fRow, 2).Value = data.Range("C18").Value` rather than copy paste.  When you get to larger data sets, you'll notice the different, and it's a good habit to form early.

Comment: @braX Tried that, the issue still persists.

Comment: @Cyril I've actually done it that way first, but the issue still persisted so I was pretty trying anything that was different to see it worked. But noted, I'll stick to that format here on through.

Comment: @nat is your source data formatted as a `string` or `date`?  Assuming it is formatted as a `date`, we'd think that braX's solution would resolve, but if you're comparing a `string` to a `string`, you may need to format `fDate` to match what is expected on your sheet.  Pleaser verify.  You can also `Debug.Print Date` to ensure that what your computer is spitting out matches what you're expecting to find.

Comment: @Cyril the values that are to be copied from the data sheet are prices derived from a stock data type and are formatted as a number value. I've just done the debug command and the date does appear in the immediate window correctly. I'm assuming the issue lies somewhere with the with statement?

Comment: @nat your `with dclose` statement doesn't appear to be used at all.  You qualified each item inside with specific references.

Comment: What is your default date format? What does the cell display when you enter `10/12/2021`? Are the columns in `dClose` formulas or values?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the columns in 'dClose' are values formatted as dates. The cells themselves display it in "DD-MM" and when you select those cells, the formula box displays the traditional format of "MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: @Cyril I'm not calling it? I presume it was since the else statement was executed.

Comment: When there are values, you can simply change the `LookIn` parameter of the `Find method` to `xlFormulas`. And you would want to add the `LookAt` parameter `xlWhole`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Great! It works perfectly as expected now. Thank you!